# How to keep n characters of each row of a pd df, where n differs by row?

Tags: python, pandas, split, warnings

I have created a df one column of which contains string values that I want to trim based on a different int value each time.
Ex.:
From:

| length | String |
| --- | --- |
| -3 | adcdef |
| -5 | ghijkl |

I wanna get:

| length | String |
| --- | --- |
| -3 | def |
| -5 | hijkl |

What I tried is the following:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    val = df['string'].iloc[i]
    n = df['length'].iloc[i]
    df['string'].iloc[i] = val[n:]
```

However, I keep getting this warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Any ideas on how I can avoid getting it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please initialize `df` in your example. Make something we can copy and use.

Comment: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')` works fine no @tdelaney?

Comment: @HenryEcker - No, that doesn't make it a complete running script. Sure, we can copy the text and do it ourselves. The point is that the posted example should be a running script. And that forms the basis for _tested_ solutions.

Comment: The advice in the pandas tag wiki, [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame with to_clipboard()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/15497888) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) all advise to use a clipboard formatted text to share dataframes.

Comment: @HenryEcker - But that is counter to MRE. Its not always possible to make a minimally reproducable script, but in this case its dead simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `apply`:

```
df["String"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["String"][x["lenght"]:], axis=1)

>>> df
   lenght String
0      -3    def
1      -5  hijkl
```